Could thermoelectricity be used instead of heat pipes?
AFAIK, heat pipes are made for fast heat transfer from the hot side into the cold side. They seem to be quite difficult to construct.
Would it be possible to achieve the same efficient and fast heat transfer with a thermoelectric loop?
E.g. I have a copper (p) and a constantan (n) wires. I short circuit them. I place the p-n junction into the hot side, the n-p junction into the cold side. Heat difference would induce current, which would cool the hot side and heat the cold side (peltier and seeback effects). I guess this would do a lot faster heat transfer than raw heat conducting metals.
What are your opinions? Would it perform "better" than heat pipes?

What are your opinions? ... questions asking for opinions are not allowed here because there is no wrong opinion

The question already has one close vote due to asking for opinions, for the reason This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.. Consider editing the question accordingly.

Peltier elements also generate additional heat (they heat the hot side by more than they cool the cold side), which seems counterproductive.

Are you actually looking for answers or do you just want someone to tell you this is a good idea?

If you have well based facts, and you don't mind wasting your time, please contribute. Otherwise "brainstorming" is welcome.

@vir I'd be also curious to point out why is it a bad idea.

Yes it has a similar effect (the two junctions will tend to equalize in temperature), however the losses are rather large so it’s not very practical.

OK. So we have a loop with a wide copper and a wide constantan wire. Both have good thermal and electrical conductivity. Temperature difference will induce current in the loop. There will be resistive losses which will make the wires warm, that heat should be dissipated at the cold side. "the two junctions will tend to equalize in temperature", that's the key point. Few percent of the heat will be transferred to the cold side with current flow speed. But the source of the resistive loses is also the hot side. These loses also makes the whole configuration warm very fast (good).


They seem to be quite difficult to construct.

I take issue with the basic premise of your question. A heat pipe could be constructed in the Bronze Age, given sufficient instructions, using techniques and materials already known at that time.
Making of semiconductors was not practiced in the Bronze Age, as far as we know.
A heat pipe is orders of magnitude easier to make than a Peltier module. You could make one in your backyard or garage, starting from raw materials (ores/minerals), in a couple of weekends worth of work + doing some reading during the week, using fairly basic tools.
And that Bronze Age heat pipe would vastly outperform any thermoelectric solution of today, just as mass-made heat pipes do. They perform extremely well relative to their size. You should try holding one in your hands and playing with it.

To be honest I haven't studied the physics of the heat pipes. I have no doubt, that they are efficient, because wildly used. The construction difficulties are depending on your supplies. If you have copper and constantan alloy plates available in the store, and you have tools to cut it into shape, than make the junctions, closed loop thermocouple is easier to make. If you have supplies and tools for the heat pipe, that is easier to construct. And yes, you may be right, that the metrics of the t-electric stuff are far away from the heat pipe metrics.

@Endre You don't need to study physics of heat pipes. Have you held one in your hand? If not, it'd be best to just do it before exploring the subject any further. Cooling as practiced in Peltier modules uses diodes, not thermoelectric junctions. The latter don't have the volumetric efficiency needed.


Would it be possible to achieve the same efficient and fast heat transfer with a thermoelectric loop?

Not just possible, but in the 1990s thermoelectric heatsink coolers were sold for Intel pentium processors in computer magazines. You can probably find retro reviews of them if you search around enough.
They do work, but the process uses a lot of power due to the low coefficient of performance of thermoelectric coolers. By Pentium 3 era circa 2000, most CPUs generated more heat than was practical to cool with a TEC, although a few 100w or greater devices were demonstrated on the pentium 4 and AMD Athlons of the early 2000s. After that the technology largely fell out of use for consumer electronics.
They are still widely used in lower power optoelectronics however.

I guess you write about thermoelectric cooling. My question is about possible use of thermoelectric effects to create a heat transfer device. Think to a simple copper plate which aims to transfer waste heat to other areas, or to create larger heat sink surfaces. Closed loop copper-constantan circuit, would have a similar aim, just with a bit more efficiency,

@Endre A thermoelectric cooler IS a heat transfer device, and in fact what you are describing. If you put energy in then it transfers heat. If you extract current then it creates a larger thermal difference to do work. But it is the same thing just with opposite direction.

You may be right. Maybe I use the wrong word. So my proposed configuration is a "heat conductor" device, like the heat pipes.

@Endre If you mean an unpowered thermoelectric cooler, it won't transfer heat well at all.

You mean the (electrically) open looped TEC, or the short circuited, or both?

@Endre Have you actually investigated how easy the heat pipes are to make, and how well they perform? A thermoelectric solution has zero advantage over a heat pipe for thermal management in a PC. Sure it can be made to work, but it’s not widely used because, by almost any metric imaginable, their performance is just so lousy relative to heat pipes. And you surely know that making a heat pipe is vastly easier than making semiconductor junctions, right? Just ponder that for a bit.

With your 20cm long 10mm diameter example rods and a temperature difference of 30K (from 330 to 300K), the amount of heat conducted normally through the rods will be about 4.6W for the copper and 0.2W for the constantan, for a total of 4.8W conducted. A well-designed thermoelectric generator operating at a much higher delta-T might be able to convert 10% of this, for 480mW of electrical power.
An ideal Carnot refrigerator operating between 330K and 300K has a COP of 10; a well-designed thermoelectric refrigerator might be 20% of this, so your 480mW of electrical power now moves 960mW from the cold reservoir for a total of 5.75W.
A heat pipe of the same size operating at a very low 1500W/m•K (4000W/m•K is more the mark) will move 18W through the same temperature gradient and since there are two of them to match the copper and constantan rods of the example, you have 36W of heat transfer.

The first question asks for an opinion. This is a physics question and the answer is not subject to opinions but physical reality.
The second question is a physics (or technology) question. The answer to that question- TE coolers are inefficient relative to other refrigerators and they consume power in order to provide cooling. A heat pipe is passive and does not require additional power input- a particularly important factor when considering, say, a laptop.

"A heat pipe is passive and does not require additional power input". Right, my drafted configuration is also "passive" doesn't require additional power input: " I have a copper (p) and a constantan (n) wires. I short circuit them."

@Endre at best you will get the sum of the thermal conductivity of both wires. If you don't, you'll transfer less heat.

@Endre, as you described in your post, it’s not passive. You either extract energy via the temperature difference and not cool beyond the thermal conductivity of the device, or you apply an external energy source and actively cool. You cannot take the energy from the temperature difference as induced current flow and use this to cool. That’s called perpetual motion.

@Endre, I think your issue is thinking that the induced current flow can then be energy that can be extracted. However, first, this effect is small. Second, this only works while you maintain that temperature gradient. Once your thermoelectric device reaches thermal equilibrium, the effect is stopped. Thus, you now have a choice, are you trying to cool or trying to generate electricity, you can’t do both, as the design requirements conflict.

I experimented with a peltier cooled enhanced water cooling loop for a project. This effectively was a traditional water being pumped around and eventually into a heat sink that needed energy removed from, and then dumped out by radiator from the loop. However, I had an additional two heat sinks that were connected to peltier modules and a second water loop connected to their hot sides. It worked and I was able to achieve below ambient temperatures.
Here’s the issue though. First, all existing thermoelectric devices are not efficient, so you end up with more heat at the end of all of this. They actually complicate your heat management instead of solving it. Second, peltier modules actually have a poor thermal conductivity, the heat transfer is occurring largely from the active operation, not the passive. This means, not only do you end up creating more heat from such a solution, but if you can’t deal with this heat, and you’re directly trying to apply it to the device (as opposed to an indirect cooling system), it will act as an insulator rather than a cooler. This makes such cooling techniques best suited for super compact and low power use cases, or where you can appropriately deal with the excess heat and want sub-ambient temperature cooling.
Compare this complexity with just a passive heat pipe system, which now looks a lot more appealing.


Yes it has a similar effect (the two junctions will tend to equalize in temperature), however the losses are rather large so it’s not very practical.

OK, I made a draft and unverified calculation with AI help (AI can be wrong, I can be wrong).
Wires are 20cm long and 10mm in diameter.
The total resistance is 33.2 mOhm.
Delta T is 30K.
The closed loop current is 37mA.
The power which works for speed up the heat transfer is 45 uW, which doesn't seem to be too much for this geometry.
Of course the conducting surface can be increased, which makes it more powerful (but maybe still not too practical).
Update
I have forgotten, that at the cold side junction, additional heat is dissipated when the current flows through the junction (it is not the raw Joule heat, but related to the Peltier effect).
Very draft AI calculation tells that it is extra 480 uW. This power is absorbed at the hot side junction.
So what I'd like to say. When there is such wire loop, one junction is attached to the hot surface, the other junction is attached to the cold surface, the following thermal conduction activities should happen:

normal phonon heat conduction, which is slow
Peltier effect will induce a current ~37mA, which:

conducts heat with ~480 uW to the cold side junction with near light speed
Joule heats the wire loop with 45 uW with near light speed



These are just to have some rough numbers, in order to see why it doesn't worth to use this method instead of heat pipes :)

Nothing wrong with AI assistance, but I’m not sure the value of posting it as an answer without verification.
